# link Flickrshow image to a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Is it possible to link an image from flickrshow gallery(I am using flickshow javascript to do slideshow of the images)to an url?

Flickrshow is a very simple Javascript slideshow for Flickr. It doesn’t require any web-development expertise, any particular Javascript frameworks, (although it works with all of them), or any hosted web space. It works in all modern web browsers, and Internet Explorer 6.
http://www.flickrshow.co.uk/example_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of Flickrshow.

I have to abide by the rules laid out by Flickr in their terms of use for the API which states that an image **must** link back to the Flickr page for that image in some way, hence the link from the image title to the Flickr page.

I can't change this as I will have my API key revoked, but if you wanted to hijack this link you *could* by using Javascript after the Flickrshow has loaded to override the events attached to that title and make it go elsewhere - be warned, you might be breaking Flickr's terms yourself too.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I had emailed you from your website regd. this question. Flickrshow is a very useful javscript.